# Terraform ec2 - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

I try to learn Terraform.

Want to install some stuff on an EC2 and connect from ssh.

I have created a new ssh-key pair for this.

When i try to `ssh -i ssh-keys/id_rsa_aws ubuntu@52.47.123.18` I got the error

> Permission denied (publickey).

Here a sample of my `.tf` script.

```
resource "aws_instance" "airflow" {
  ami                    = "ami-0d3f551818b21ed81"
  instance_type          = "t3a.xlarge"
  key_name               = "admin"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh-group.id]
  tags = {
    "Name" = "airflow"
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.ec2_subnet.id
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "admin" {
  key_name   = "admin"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa ........" # I cat my key.pub fot this
}
```

#### EDIT

Thanks to @GrzegorzOledzki I see that the issue come from my subnet work. Here the files.

> gateway.tf

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "my-gateway"
  }
}
```

> network.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
  tags = {
    Name = "my-vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "airflow_ip" {
  instance = aws_instance.airflow.id
  vpc      = true
}
```

> security_group.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ssh-group" {

  name = "ssh-group"

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  ingress {
    # TLS (change to whatever ports you need)
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"
    # Please restrict your ingress to only necessary IPs and ports.
    # Opening to 0.0.0.0/0 can lead to security vulnerabilities.
    cidr_blocks = ["my.ip.from.home/32"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

> subnet.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "ec2_subnet" {
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.my_vpc.cidr_block, 3, 1)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  availability_zone = "eu-west-3c"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "my_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.my_gateway.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "my_route_table"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet_association" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.my_route_table.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.ec2_subnet.id
}
```

#### EDIT 2

I destroy everything then rebuilt it and it's working. I'm not sure but I have create my EC2 instance before making and linking the custom-vpc, subnet and security group. It was like something (what ?) went wrong and it couldn't not reassign everything to my instance.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't ask you for `The authenticity of host .* can't be established.`?

Comment: Also if that helps you - I've just tried your `.tf` (modified it slightly for network setup, i.e. removed the vpc and subnet stuff; added my key) and it worked for me (with the same AMI which I believe is an Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: `id_rsa_aws` != `key.pub` Could it be it?

Comment: First question, NO.
Second, hum ! Weird. It's 20.04 but yes it's ubuntu. The key is something you have create on your computer right ?
Third, where did you get the id_rsa_aws ? in the key `public_key` I should put my... public key, no ? The one ending `by .pub`

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki you are right. There is something wrong with the subnet work. If I try to instanciate a new EC2 but w/o the vpc and subnet it's working. I will post the rest of my script to look at

Comment: Problems with subnet wouldn't manifest with "Permission denied (publickey)". The message is clearly a response from a SSH server (maybe from a different server than you would expect, but still).

Comment: I destroy all my instances, didn't touch the script, apply it, make it worked. So I have no idea why I had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue and the fix for me too was to just terraform destroy and then rebuilding the infrastructure.

The root cause for my issues was that I had first created and set the key pair for the ec2 instance, but I didn't output/save the private key at all. After creating the ec2 instance with the key pair, I added output + save functionality to the generated ssh keys, but they were actually not the key pair that was set to the ec2 instance, but instead just a new generated one. Now that I generated the key pair set for the newly created instance and saved the output from the private key I could ssh successfully in to the instance

Answer (score 0):

Currenly that pem key has read permission only for users (chmod 400 *.pem). In this case, you need to enable read permission for others also (chmod 404 / chmod o=r *.pem).